# Can't understand how these two functions work

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const catchAsync = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(err => next(err));

  };
};

exports.createTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      tours: newTour,
    },
  });
});
```

Can someone please explain to me how does these two functions work together.
inside the catchAsync function we have a return and it returns a new function but why do we type (req, res, next) inside the function as a parameters ?
I don't even know how to tell my questions

Tried to understand the code, but it didn't work

Comment: catchAsync takes one function, returns another function. The second function passes is arguments to the first function, and also automatically calls next(err) if the first function fails.

Comment: That's "middleware".  why (req, res, next)?  Read the [writing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) guide.  catchAsync ensures that there are no unhandled promise rejections by adding a rejection handler (`fn()` becomes `fn().catch()`) and ensures that an exception is handled by passing the exception details through the middleware chain.  That way you can serve up an HTTP error response or 500 error instead of crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exports.createTour`  Whatever is calling this function will be expecting a function that has parameters `(req, res, next) => {}`  in express this is known as middleware, `req` would be the request, `res` would be the response, and `next` would be if we decided not to handle this request or pass the error to the `next` handler.

Now we could just create the `createTour` function without `catchAsync` and it would look like ->

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        tours: newTour,
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
}
```

So basically all `catchAsync` is doing is creating a function wrapper that uses the promise returned from function `fn` that is passed and uses the `Promise.catch` callback that will automatically execute `next` with the error.  It saves you having to implement your own `try / catch` on every route handler.

So how does `catchAsync` work.  In Javascript a function can return a function.

```
const catchAsync = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) =>
```

In the above `catchAsync` is a function that creates a new function that takes `req, res, next` as parameters.  These parameters will get filled in by the parameters that have been sent to `exports.createTour`, now that we have these parameters we can act like a middleman to the function we pass to it, your `const newTour = await.....` bit.  Inside `catchAsync` calling `fn()` will be calling the code you supplied, and because `catchAsync` is calling the function we can capture any errors and pass into the `next` callback, that original came from the parameter sent to `createTour`.

It might seem really cryptic, but it's a really common practice to do this with Javascript, to help understand it a little bit more, lets pretend and make something simpler.  Lets say I wanted to create a function that could be used to surround a string, with some supplied string, we could then make 3 new functions by just calling this function creator and passing say a single quote, for doing quoted strings, a double quote for doing double quoted strings, and why not a pipe symbol to finish.

Below is a working snippet doing this, if you can follow and understand, it shouldn't take much more to follow on what catchAsync is doing.

```js
function txtSurrounder(surroundTxt) {
  return (txt) => 
    `${surroundTxt}${txt}${surroundTxt}`;
}

const quouted = txtSurrounder("'");
const double = txtSurrounder('"');
const pipeIt = txtSurrounder('!');

console.log(quouted("This is quoted"));
console.log(double("This is double quotes"));
console.log(pipeIt("Why not pipes"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I already understood this piece of the code, the first function is causing me a problem where it returns a function with 3 parameters(req, res, next), and inside that anonymous function, we call the fn function with the same 3 parameters.
So this is the piece of code that I don't understand

Comment: @HasanAlilhadi  I've expanded a little bit more, hopefully makes a little bit more sense now..